# merge with if statement data step

Tags: sas

During optimization code, I face with some problem. I need to use **ONE** only data step

```
data step1;
merge table1(in=in1) table2(in=in2 rename=(field2=field22));
by field1;
If (in1=1 and in2=1) then output;run;

data step2;
set step1;
If field1=field22 then mark=1 output;run;

proc sql;
create table step3 as select sum(mark1) from step2 group by field1;quit;run;
```

Is it possible to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Some example data would be useful here.  I notice you don't have a `by` statement in your merge, so it will join by row number.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @Keith Thank you for attention) I forgot to rewrite it. In original version its exists

Comment: Can you add a description of the purpose of the program? Looking at the program it seems that you want to count how many times the value of FIELD1=FIELD2 in TABLE2 for records that exist in TABLE1.  Do you want to have values of FIELD1 that have no matches, that is where sum(MARK1) = 0?

Comment: @Tom you are absolutelly right. If Sum(mark1) = .  there is no matches in table2 for this join. So? this missmatching I need to find) It works with code I wrote. But I need to write it smater in ONE data step. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to group by FIELD1 and count how many records in TABLE2 have FIELD1=FIELD2, but only when FIELD1 also appears in TABLE1.

```
data want ;
  do until (last.field1);
    merge table1 (in=in1) table2(in=in2 where=(field1=field2));
    by field1;
    count=sum(count,in1 and in2);
  end;
  keep field1 count;
run;
```

If you want to find all cases where there are any values where FIELD11 ne FIELD22 then you can add a double DOW loop.

```
data want ;
  do until (last.field1);
    merge table1 (in=in1) table2(in=in2) ;
    by field1;
    if in1 and in2 and (field11 ne field22) then missmatch=1;
  end;
  do until (last.field1);
    merge table1 (in=in1) table2(in=in2) ;
    by field1;
    if missmatch then output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: I need to merge two tables (analog left join), then I need to make marks then sum it. this is some kind of bussiness case. Final Idea is to check one observation from multiple observation from table2.  If any of observations from table 2 (join on table1.field1) do not have field1=field22 matching than I have to see this observations. Sorry if I can not explain it gradually. Do you catch the idea?

Comment: So you want the full set of records for cases where there are any miss-matches?

Comment: The case that I need only observations from table1 that do not have any matches from table2 (table1.field11 ne table2.field2)

Comment: You simply want the set of values of TABLE1.FIELD1 that do not appear in TABLE2.FIELD2?  If so then why are you looking that variable TABLE2.FIELD1 at all?

Comment: Two table merging by field1 (one to many). Than in table1 and table 2 I need to find table1.filed11=table2.field22 matching. If there is at least one matching, then everything fine and go to next table1.field1, If there is no matching at all (in table2) then I need to see this table1.field1.

Comment: So the double DOW loop code above could do that easily. Adjust the first loop to calculate the condition should cause this set of FIELD1 records to get flagged for output. Then use that calculated field to conditionally output the records in the second DOW loop.